# Приведение типов при ссылке на ресурсы

Tags: java, android

В Activity создал переменную

```
private TextView txtTitle;
```

и в методе `onCreate()` ссылаюсь на него так

```
txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
```

Студия серым отображает тип, к которому я привожу переменную. Т.е. теперь необязательно писать `(TextView)`?

Comment: А вопрос в чем?

Comment: Вопрос в том нужно ли по-прежнему указывать тип или нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В SDK 26 поменялась сигнатура метода `findViewById(...)`. Раньше она была такая:

```
public View findViewById(int id);
```

и, соответственно, нужно было явно приводить тип. В SDK 26+ метод выглядит следующим образом:

```
public <T extends View> T findViewById(int id);
```

и приводить тип не нужно.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.